# Managing shared/singleton client objects in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm after a bit of patterns guidance. I am writing a React front end (using NextJS) to a back end (based on FeathersJS) that relies on a singleton client object. The client will be needed in many different components up and down the tree, basically to make requests to the server for various things.

In the simple examples online, this `client` object is managed as a shared global, imported wherever it is needed.

```
// client.js

import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from '@feathersjs/client';

const socket = io();
const client = feathers();

client.configure(feathers.socketio(socket));
client.configure(feathers.authentication());

export default client;

// consumer somewhere

import client from './client';
client.doStuff()
```

The problem with this is that the global initialisation interacts badly with webpack and server-side rendering, and in general doing initialisation like this in the global scope feels wrong.

Where would you best put this so that (a) it's initialised early but only on client-side; (b) it's easy to get hold of and use from components up and down the component tree?

One option would obviously be just to manage a global singleton that's initialised on demand when first used:

```
let client = null;

function getClient() {
    global client;
    if(client === null) {
        // initialise client
    }
    return client;
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more canonical way in React, e.g. using context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The client will be needed in many different components up and down the tree ... But I'm wondering if there's a more canonical way in React, e.g. using context?

I think React Context is good for these sorts of singleton objects, especially if the object will be used in many spots up and down the three. There are many, many examples of this in practice. I would consider myself a judicious user of context, and I would say this is what the Context API was designed for. For example, take [`useApolloClient`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#useapolloclient). It consumes an  Apollo Client that was previously put into context by an [`ApolloProvider`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#apolloprovider) so that it can be used anywhere in the tree.

> The problem with this is that the global initialisation interacts badly with webpack and server-side rendering ... Where would you best put this so that (a) it's initialised early but only on client-side; (b) it's easy to get hold of and use from components up and down the component tree?

Yes, initializing these objects in the render tree on the server side can be tricky or bad. If you're using something like Next.js , it makes sense to initialize these objects "above" the render tree, either at a top-level module scope or in [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).

Comment: Interestingly the code behind `useApolloContext` appears to stash a react context globally on the React object to make sure its a singleton. I tried to make something similar work and found the context wasn’t initialised in some of my event handlers, but I must be doing something wrong. Will debug more.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "stash a react context globally on the React object to make sure it's a singleton" (perhaps they are doing something to avoid issues when multiple versions of the library are installed by accident), but I did not mean to endorse the Apollo Client codebase, which is riddled IMO with "bad stuff" (i.e. getDataFromTree). Just meant to point to this pattern, which is quite common beyond Apollo Client.

Comment: Hah, got it. I've ended up with this pattern which seems reasonable: https://gist.github.com/optilude/2bb137fff73651e469d96825fa0c5861

Comment: Makes sense to me, presuming you never need to use the client in `getInitialProps` and don't want server renders to include data that is provided by the client. If you initialize the client like this, you'll need to fetch data on the client side and then render again once that data has arrived.

Comment: These examples are kind of convoluted/involved, but see how they store the client in module scope (client side) so that it can be used in static methods that are "above" the renders: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/21be4c054b6e08a7baab3122b3bcdaca5d84702d/examples/with-apollo/lib/apollo.js#L9 and https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/21be4c054b6e08a7baab3122b3bcdaca5d84702d/examples/with-react-relay-network-modern/lib/createEnvironment/client.js#L10